# C++ error:[ invalid operands to binary expression ('std::map<int, std::function<void ()>, std::less<int>...]

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers, stdmap, std-function

With this following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include "main.h"
std::map<int,std::function<void()>> fnc_event_to;
void testFunction();
void initialize() {
  fnc_event_to[1] = testFunction;
  bool boolean = fnc_event_to[2] == testFunction;//<- error
  pros::lcd::initialize();
  pros::lcd::print(2,"%d",boolean);
}
```

I recieve this error:

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('std::map<int, std::function<void ()>, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::function<void ()> > > >::mapped_type' (aka 'std::function<void ()>') and 'void (*)()')
```

How come I can assign the function pointer to the map but I am not able to compare it with a function pointer?

Also, if a key is not defined, what will the map return?

Is there a way to compare the `std::function` so I can see whether its a null function pointer or is it defined already?

Or is there a better solution for this? Originally, I'm using a `while(1)` loop to trap the thread and the map is just a map of what the program should do when a variable reaches the key(int). The variable is changed in a separate task so its multitasking. I couldn't use the `.contains()` method since I'm not using C++ 20 yet.

Comment: Did you try `fnc_event_to[2] == std::function<void()>(testFunction)`? In any case you are likely to be disappointed because all non-null `std::function` objects compare as non-equal.

Comment: i tried `std::function<void()>(testFunction)` and it displays this error:`invalid operands to binary expression ('std::map<int, std::function<void ()>, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::function<void ()> > > >::mapped_type' (aka 'std::function<void ()>') and 'std::function<void ()>')`

Comment: It really sad that I couldn't use the `.contains()` method. It would make my life a lot easier. Is still doesn't support c++ 20

Comment: Or is there a better solution for this? originally, im using a while(1) loop to trap the thread and the map is just a map of what the program should do when a variable reaches the key(int). The variable is changed in a separate task so its multitasking. I couldn't use the `.contains()`method since im not using c++ 20 yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just posted for reference. Answers are quoted from @0x499602D2 and @LightnessRacesInOrbit.
Either use:

```
if (fnc_event_to[2]){
}
```

Or

```
if(fnc_event_to.find(2) != fnc_event_to.end()){
}
```

Be aware that the first option will create an empty element, so if you give the map the same value, it will already be created, and it will return true.

Comment: Correct - but note that the first example will _create_ (via default-construction) the element if it doesn't already exist, so the second example will not work after that. You may wish to distinguish between the map holding a function that is "empty", and the map not holding a function.

Comment: Thanks! If didn't know I will have a hard time debugging later!

Answer (score 0):

The standard class std::function has only these comparison operator ==

```
template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
bool operator==(const function<R(ArgTypes...)>&, nullptr_t) noexcept;

template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
bool operator==(nullptr_t, const function<R(ArgTypes...)>&) noexcept;
```

So you can only check whether an object of the class is "empty".

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm very new to C++, then what should I put the rside of the comparison?

Comment: You should instead make it so that you don't need the comparison. Why do you think you need the comparison?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I just need to check if the std::function in the map exists since I will be throwing random numbers from a sensor at the map until one is valid, then run the function. Or do you suggest a better solution? (See the bottom of my post)

Comment: @Arandomprogramer Your code tries to see whether the function is the same as another function, not whether it "exists". Which is it that you want? And what do you mean by "exists"? Can you give an example of a function that does not exist? Did you mean a default-constructed `std::function`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit By not existing, I mean that the key is undefined. Say that i declared a item in the map:`fnc_event_to[1] = test function`. When I give a key to the map that is undefined (like `fnc_event_to[2]`), how can I test if that key exists or not?

Comment: @aRandomProgramer It'll be default-constructed so you can use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool

Comment: Thanks! But why isn't `bool boolean = fnc_event_to[2]);` working?

Comment: @aRandomProgramer Consider using the `.find()` method to see if a key exists (i.e `bool exists = fnc_event_to.find(2) != fnc_event_to.end()`

Comment: Thanks, @0x499602D2 and LightnessRacesinOrbit. Both solved my problem :)